# Updating BLOB from MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, workbench

I have a problem with one SQL statement. I am trying to update something in a table which is a Blob field with a pdf. And it's not working.

```
UPDATE employees 
SET resume = LOAD_FILE('C:\Users\gaby\Desktop\sample_resume.pdf') 
WHERE id = 1;
```

If I use the above command the result is null. If I use the below command the result is not null, there is a pdf but it is empty.

```
UPDATE employees 
SET resume = 'C:\Users\gaby\Desktop\sample_resume.pdf'
WHERE id = 1;
```

I can do this update using JDBC, it works perfect. But I want to do it from workbench too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it done by moving the image(`fileName.jpg`) file first in to below folder(in my case) `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads` and then I executed below command and it works for me,

```
update employees set file=LOAD_FILE('C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/fileName.jpg') where id = 1;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if all conditions described in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) are given.

> `LOAD_FILE(file_name)`
>
> Reads the file and returns the file contents as a string. To use this function, the file must be located on the server host, you must specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the `FILE` privilege. The file must be readable by all and its size less than `max_allowed_packet` bytes. If the `secure_file_priv` system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.
>
> If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the preceding conditions is not satisfied, the function returns `NULL`.

`load_file()` returns `NULL`, (at least) one of the conditions must fail.